# Rails 4.0.3 REST upload file to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, curl, paperclip

I'm learning Rails and want to build a REST API

However, I got a problem in PUT file to server

I want to send a file form client to rails server via "curl -T /path/to/file" this command like S3 API

But, I cannot find any resolve without a page which use upload file bar to upload file

How can I build PUT file API via rails

thx